# A naive example of discrete Fourier transformation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

We know a discrete Fourier transformation with discrete $n$ and continuous $x_1,x_2$:
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-in(x_1-x_2)\frac{2\pi}{L}}=L\delta(x_1-x_2)
$$
with Dirac delta function $\delta$.

and a discrete Fourier transformation with discrete $n$ and discrete $x_1,x_2$:
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-in(x_1-x_2)\frac{2\pi}{L}}=L\delta_{x_1-x_2,0}
$$
with Kronecker delta function $\delta$.

> **Question: what is the discrete Fourier transformation with discrete $n$ and discrete $x_1,x_2$** below:
>   $$
> \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n \;e^{-in(x_1-x_2)\frac{2\pi}{L}}=?
> $$

Comment:
For continuous $x_1,x_2$ case, I have obtained, and it is easy to see that 
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n e^{-in(x_1-x_2)\frac{2\pi}{L}}=i\frac{L^2}{2\pi} \frac{\partial \delta(x_1-x_2)}{\partial {(x_1-x_2)}}
$$

For discrete $x_1,x_2$,
I obtained a form of $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n \;e^{-in(x_1-x_2)\frac{2\pi}{L}}=\frac{L\delta_{x_1-x_2,0}}{1-e^{-i(x_1-x_2)\frac{2\pi}{L}}}=\frac{L^2}{2\pi}\frac{\delta_{x_1-x_2,0}}{i(x_1-x_2)+\dots}.$$

I would like to make sure that my answer is really the correct case?

Answer (score 1):

The initial identity is wrong. First, the series does not converge in the classical sense, and second, as a series of distributions the limit is periodic, what is called a Dirac comb.
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-2\pi i\, n(x_1-x_2)\frac{1}{L}}=L\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\delta(x_1-x_2+kL)
$$
See [Poisson summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Distributional_formulation).

There is no discrete case, since then the sums are not even interpretable as distributions and thus diverge in all circumstances.

---

The second formula has the same caveats, the right side should be the derivative of a Dirac comb. The general approach is correct.

Comment: Hi LutzL, is your $k=2\pi n/L$? can you be more careful about the notation - introducing $k$ ?

Comment: sorry, I think you $k$ is just any $k$ to sum over...

Comment: why $x_1$, $x_2$ cannot take discrete values? In physics, this happens in quantum mechanics on a lattice (condensed matter or solid state), where $x = N\; a $ is a discrete value $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ on the lattice, $2 \pi n/L$ is the momentum mode also taking discrete values $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @LutzL and mystery: See also this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817568/an-alternate-derivation-of-poisson-summation-formula-and-discrete-fourier-tran

Comment: Yes, k is a summation index, an integer. -- No, there is no sensible interpretation of the series if $x_1-x_2$ is integer, essentially you have then series of the type $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}1$ or $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^k$ which do not converge. -- And the first integral in the other post does also not exist in the classical sense, there is a reason that proofs are heavy on boilerplate.