# an "alternate derivation" of Poisson summation formula and discrete Fourier transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817442/a-naive-example-of-discrete-fourier-transformation), I am trying to do a derivation of a Poisson summation formula.

My starting point is this:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{i k x} dx=\delta(k)
$$

> I simply wish to take the continuum by the following, with $k_n=\frac{2\pi n}{L}$:
>   $$
> \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}   e^{-in (x_1-x_2) \frac{2\pi}{L} } =\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-i k_n (x_1-x_2) } (k_{n+1}-k_n)\frac{L}{2\pi}  \to \int e^{-ik (x_1-x_2)} dk \frac{L}{2\pi} =L \delta(x_1-x_2)  ---Eq.(1)
> $$

The arrow $\to$ is taking the continuum, so:

$$
(k_{n+1}-k_n) \to dk,\\
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \to \int
$$

Follow the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817442/a-naive-example-of-discrete-fourier-transformation) on [Poisson_summation_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Distributional_formulation), I should have

> $$
> \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}   e^{-in (x_1-x_2) \frac{2\pi}{L} } =\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} L \delta(x_1-x_2-mL) ---Eq.(2)
> $$

**Question 1: so what is wrong with my derivation on Eq.(1)?**

**Question 2: how to derive Eq.(2) by taking the continuum?**

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is related to the total periodicity of the system, if the system size is $L$, then $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x_1-x_2-mL)= \delta(x_1-x_2)$.